# TypeError: not enough arguments for format string in Robot-Framework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

**Versions:**

Python: 32-bit
robotframework: 3.0
robotframework-databaseLibrary: 1.0.0
cx_oracle: 6.2
windows 7 64-bit
IDE: Pycharm

**Robot Code**

```
***Settings ****  
Library  DatabaseLibrary

***Variables****
${dbUsername} =  ABC
${dbPassword} =  PQR 
{dbHost} = 12.32.1
${dbName} =  A123
${String} =  ${dbUsername}/${dbPassword}@${dbHost}/${dbName}
${dbapiModuleName} =  cx_Oracle

***Keywords****  
Connect to DB  
 connect to database using custom params  ${dbapiModuleName}  ${String} 

*** Test Cases****  
Get Data  
 Connect to DB
```

But I'm getting this error ***"TypeError: not enough arguments for format string"***.

Initially I've used command :
**connect to database**   `${dbapiModuleName}  ${dbName}  ${dbUsername}  ${dbPassword}  ${dbHost}  ${dbPort}`     on which I got error   "**TypeError: 'database' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**
".
So, I changed it to
**connect to database using custom params**  `${dbapiModuleName}  ${String}`

Can anyone help me out in this.

Comment: The error message is pretty clear - you give not enough arguments.

Comment: But in command connect to database using custom params I'm passing only two arguments one is cx_Oracle and one String. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Maybe you have not enough spaces between the two arguments.

Comment: Please edit the question with proper code formatting - the way it is currently, it's barely readable. Whitespace is important in Robotframework, if you don't have enough spaces or some similar syntax error, it won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the versions of **cx_Orcale to 6.2.1** and **DatabaseLibrary to 1.0.1** and it worked for me now I'm able to connect to DB.